# writing a custom function Multiply the average of x,y

Tags: python, python-3.x

writing a custom function Multiply the average of x,y

```
x=[17,13,12,15,16,14,16,16,18,19]
y=[94,73,59,80,93,85,66,79,77,91]
```

I have a two list and I want to calculate its average. After getting the two average I want to multiply

This code i have tried to achieve this functionality but not able to get the expected output. if any help appreciated

```
def X_bar_y_bar(x,y):
    x1=[]
    y1=[]
    ab=[]
    for i in x:
        result_x1=i-sum(x)/float(len(x))
        result_x1=result_x
        x1.append(result_x1)

    for k in y:
        result_y1=k-sum(y)/float(len(y))
        result_y1=result_y
        y1.append(result_y1)
    total=0
    for i in x1:
        for j in y1:
            r1=i*j
            total = +r1
            print("{:.2f}".format(total))
```

Desired output:

```
20.02
17.42
74.52
-0.18
5.32
-5.48
-0.28
-6.48
38.42
```

Comment: Can't you use NumPy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have to use 'numpy', then you can use the following code:

```
x=[17,13,12,15,16,14,16,16,18,19]
y=[94,73,59,80,93,85,66,79,77,91]

def X_bar_y_bar(x,y):
    xave = sum(x)/float(len(x))
    yave = sum(y)/float(len(y))

    for i in range(len(x)):
        result=((x[i]-xave)*(y[i]-yave))
        print("{:.2f}".format(result))

X_bar_y_bar(x,y)
```

Few changes compared to your code:

1) the average is calculated once, you should bring it out of the loop
2) the assignment, 'result_x1=result_x', doesn't do anything, skip that

Answer (score 1):

You should really use NumPy for things like these:

```
import numpy as np

x=np.array([17,13,12,15,16,14,16,16,18,19])
y=np.array([94,73,59,80,93,85,66,79,77,91])

(x - np.mean(x)) * (y - np.mean(y))
# array([20.02, 17.42, 74.52, -0.18,  5.32, -8.48, -5.48, -0.28, -6.48, 38.42])
```